# how to properly use INSERT OR REPLACE?

Tags: sql, qml

This is what i got:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Settings (sitem TEXT, ccolor TEXT, ncolor TEXT)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS sindex ON Settings (sitem, ccolor, ncolor)
```

but when i try to insert a value and then replace it running this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Settings (sitem) VALUES ("something")
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Settings (sitem) VALUES ("something else")
```

This is what i get in the `sitem` column:

```
     sitem
---------------
something
something else
```

it does not replace it, just make another value even if it's unique, any help?

Answer (score 0):

The sitem field is part of the primary key and so is used to identify the row to do the replace on. You can't update the row in the way you want because the database can't tell that you want to replace the first record with the second one, so it does an insert instead.

Comment: so, i must make a primary key?? i'm new to sql in general.